# Dynamic Height UILabel works after moving offscreen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, sizetofit

I am trying to create multi-line dynamic UILabels in UITableViewCells.  I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a 'comment' label.  The cell and the label are created in storyboard.

I can compute the heights of the UITableViewCells properly based on the multi-line data to be stored in the UILabel (using heightForRowAtIndexPath).  However, my problem lies in the actual UILabel content.  The UILabel content will display only 1 line of data on table load.  However, once a cell containing multiline UILabel data moves offscreen and comes back on screen, the multi-line data appears properly in the UILabel with multiple lines.  Is there any way to fix this so that the multi-line data appears properly on table load?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cCell = (CustomCell *)cell;
    MyObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cCell.commentLabel.frame = CGRectMake(65.0f, 28.0f, 243.0f, 200.0f);
    cCell.commentLabel.text = MyObject.multi_line_text_data;
    cCell.commentLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    cCell.commentLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    cCell.commentLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    cCell.commentLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cCell.commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cCell.commentLabel sizeToFit];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: yes, I am using autolayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing this in the storyboard, you can set the necessary label properties there (lineBreakMode and number of lines). Just give the label a specific width constraint and constraints to the top, bottom, and left sides of the cell. Then, in code use sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: in heightForRowAtIndexPath: to calculate the appropriate height for the cell based on the content of the label -- the label, because of its constraints, will expand along with the cell to the proper size. Something like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize rowSize = [self.theData[indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return rowSize.height + 30;
}
```

Here, 260 was the width I gave my label in IB, and the 30 is a fudge factor (determined empirically) to account for padding above and below the label.

Comment: Thanks!   I forgot to put a width constraint on the UILabel in the story board.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problems. Unchecking Autolayout can fix it.